# Swift can not see objc class function using block

Tags: ios, swift

I am using HMSegmentedControl(https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl) in swift.

When I tried to use the following function

`- (void)setIndexChangeBlock:(IndexChangeBlock)indexChangeBlock;`

Xcode could not find his function when I used the following syntax

```
categoriesView.setIndexChangeBlock {

}
```

It says "HMSegmentedControl does not have a member named categoriesView.setIndexChangeBlock. I noticed another function in HMSegmentedControl that does not use block has been recognized by Xcode.

```
- (void)setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSUInteger)index animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

How to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Set block using this**

```
categoriesView.indexChangeBlock = { (index) in

  if index == 0 {
  //Do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setIndexChangeBlock:` method expects a block parameter `IndexChangeBlock`, which is [defined](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl/blob/master/HMSegmentedControl/HMSegmentedControl.h#L13) as follows:

```
typedef void (^IndexChangeBlock)(NSInteger index);
```

This means it expects an `NSInteger` parameter. You would need to call the method as follows:

```
categoriesView.setIndexChangeBlock { (i: Int) -> () in

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set visible scrollview area like:

```
func segmentedControlChangedValue(segmentedControl: HMSegmentedControl) {
        self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect.init(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex), y: (self.scrollView.frame.origin.y), width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: (self.scrollView.frame.size.height)), animated: true)

}
```